# Is there a way to view a list of PyTable file marks?

Tags: pytables

In the Pytable file class you can `get_current_mark()`, `goto(mark)`, `undo(mark)`, `mark()`, etc. but is there a way to see a list of all available marks? 
 Reference: http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/file_class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not part of the public API - which does not provide a way of doing what you are asking for - there are two private members that you can use.  The first is `File._markers` which is a dictionary of mark names to the their row number in the `File._actionlog` table, which is a table in the file of all of the actions taken thus far.  I think that `sorted(File._markers.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])` is probably what you want.